# SQL developer counting and showing info

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT PERSONALINFO.FN, 
   PERSONALINFO.SN       
 FROM PERSONALINFO
 JOIN BOOKING ON BOOKED.EMAIL = PERSONALINFO.EMAIL        
 HAVING COUNT(BOOKEDE.EMAIL) > 2
```

I am using sqldeveloper to try and count how many times an email comes up in the booking database, and if the email comes up more than twice it will get the personalinfo from the personalinfo database and show it, but I just can't seem to get it working at all,  am I am quite lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an aggregate function, you need a `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT PERSONALINFO.FIRSTNAME, 
       PERSONALINFO.SECONDNAME       
FROM PERSONALINFO
JOIN BOOKING ON BOOKING.EMAIL = PERSONALINFO.EMAIL
GROUP BY PERSONALINFO.FIRSTNAME, PERSONALINFO.SECONDNAME        
HAVING COUNT(BOOKING.EMAIL) > 2
```

Comment: Thanks man! any tips on how to order it by descending booking.email counts, I tried ORDER BY BOOKING.EMAIL and ORDER BY COUNT(BOOKING.EMAIl)

Comment: If you add COUNT(BOOKING.EMAIL) as a 3rd selected column,  you may be able to do ORDER BY 3 DESC.  I know that works in SQL Server, and I'm not sure if that's a SQL Server specific trick.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b668/1/0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PL.FIRSTNAME, PL.SECONDNAME, PL.EMAIL FROM PERSONALINFO PL
  INNER JOIN BOOKING B ON B.EMAIL = PL.EMAIL
  WHERE COUNT(B.EMAIL)>2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT  pi.FIRSTNAME ,
        pi.SECONDNAME ,
        pi.EMAIL
FROM    (select email
         from BOOKING b
         group by email
         having count(*) > 2
        ) b join
        PERSONALINFO pi
        ON b.EMAIL = pi.EMAIL;
```

Your initial query has several problems.  Some are syntactic, such as having a `count()` function in the `where` clause rather than in a `having` clause.  Some are logical, such as the fact that duplicate emails in `PERSONALINFO` will also cause "matches" to the query, even when there is only one booking.

This version fixes these problems by aggregating `BOOKING` first, extracting the emails of interest, and then joining to the other table.

Also, I added table aliases into the query (the `pi` and `b`).  This makes the query easier to read and maintain.